# Using a modified Nokogiri to parse Wikitext?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, wiki

Apologies for the length of this question, it's more of a "is this possible" than "how do I do this".

My objective is to remove everything but plain text from Wikipedia markup -- tables, templates, formatting. Whether these are in [wikitext markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_markup) (e.g. `''bold text''`) or HTML (`<b>bold text</b>`).

Wikipedia text is a mix of custom tags: templates `{{ ... }}`, tables `{| ... |}`, links `[[ ... ]]` and HTML elements. Parsing it is kind of a nightmare. You can't use regular expressions because the tags can be nested, and it can contain HTML so almost anything is possible. Some of the text within the HTML I'd want to keep (stuff within bold text), but other things like tables would need to be stripped entirely.

I thought about re-purposing an XML parser like Nokogiri, adding `{{`/`}}` as alternatives to `<x>`/`</x>`.

Does anyone who knows Nokogiri (or another Ruby XML parser) know if this is possible or even a good idea?

My alternative is to repurpose an existing parser like [WikiCloth](https://github.com/nricciar/wikicloth) for the wiki markup, and then try to remove any leftover HTML via another method.

Comment: It's a context-free language, so libxml should be able to parse it. I'm not sure if you can change the parse tree. Probably write your own parser.

Comment: Why not render it to HTML with something that understands all the markup and then use Nokogiri to pull out the raw text?

Comment: @Phrogz I could do that, I was just hoping to save some time as there's many gigabytes of text to parse.

Comment: Were you able to patch REXML for this?  Trying to do the same thing myself and struggling to find a decent solution.

Comment: My quick solution was just to do 2 gsubs of the opening and closing wikitext tag, replacing them with xml tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good idea. However, it would not be possible for you to 'patch' Nokogiri, *"adding `{{/}}` as alternatives to `<x>/</x>`"*. This is because the bulk of the work done by Nokogiri—parsing and XPath and generating the string representation of a DOM—is actually done by [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) in the back end. You'd have to patch and recompile libxml2 (and then rebuild Nokogiri against your new version)…but at that point I have no idea how Nokogiri would behave.

You might have better luck trying to patch [REXML](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/), since that is written in pure Ruby.